# CollectionView Cell subview on top of header

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

So, I have CollectionView that contains a header (used as a stretchy header) and underneath is just a cell containing a picture surrounded with red circles. 
Is there a way to bring the red circles picture on top of the header picture, and still being part of the collectionView cell? Whatever I do the header is always on top. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: What I would suggest is put your stretchy header imageView behind the collectionView. And make the collectionview background color to clear. Apply the same logic from didScroll in to the background imageView. Does that make sense?

Comment: @arvidurs Good call, I think you just became my best friend now :) With a bit of tweaking to the didScroll logic and works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great! glad you figured it out

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 choices:

1. set the header view clipsToBounds flag equals true
2. set the header view UIImageView content mode equals to aspect fit

Comment: this will not make the cell go on top

Comment: As i understand from the question image above. the header image is just scaled because the content mode of the image in the header is scale to fill.